# Losing data when passing a pandas DataFrame through a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to call a function from a Jupyter Notebook (VSCode) that returns a pandas DataFrame **df**, however I have noticed that some rows of **df** are lost in the process. I have tried returning **df** itself and a deepcopy but both result in lost rows. When I run the code used in the function inside the notebook no data is lost, so I suspect the problem arises when passing **df** through the function. I should mention that the original size of **df** is 50558 and when returned the size goes down to 49997 (lost 561 elements).

A very crude sample of the code:

In the 'Reader.py' file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

def getDF():
    #reading files
    (...)
    #processing data
    (...)

    rows_list = []
    for piece_of_data in data:
        #adding piece_of_data to dictionary dict  
        (...)  

        rows_list.append(dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
    return df
```

In the Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from Reader import getDF

df = getDF()
```

I know I could simply include the function code in the notebook and start from there but I would rather not have a big chunk of code with the creation of the dataframe if possible.

Comment: Have you tried checking the size data and of rows_list when calling the `getDF` function? Is the path to data absolute or can it be that a different dataset is beign loaded when you cal lit from the notebook?

Comment: I did check the size (edited the question, I thought df.size returned the number of rows) of **df**, the number of rows of **rows_list** and they matched. The path is the same. I tried calling the function and running the function in the same Jupyter Notebook and the results differed: 
- calling the function returned a **df** with a reduced number of elements;
- running the function created **df** as it should;

I tried calling the function from another .py file (instead of a J notebook) and it worked fine. Maybe the issue is in the Jupyter Notebook itself?

Comment: It's very strange and sounds like an issue with Jupyter Notebook indeed. Maybe one last thing to check could be if the same rows are getting deleted every time you call it from the notebook or if it's random.

Comment: Since **df** is quite large I cannot be 100% sure but I would say yes! I noticed the problem when I found a point in a plot was constantly missing, and still is everytime I get **df** from the getDF().

Comment: Have you tried testing this process in Jupyter outside of VS Code? When the amount of data decreases, will the data still be lost?